# regex two first letters

Tags: regex

How do read two first letters and delete line?

This code remove all line where is GG
`.*gg.*.*.*`

ggang - delete
gangg -undelete

Comment: what editor/programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Tested in notepad++:

find:    ^(gg.*)$

replace:   (leave blank)

in:
ggang
gangg

out:
gangg